# How to achieve the effect that the image will pop up when sliding left image to the right?

Tags: javascript, jquery

The interactive movement is a slide from left to right, how to add another interaction, so the image or some words will pop up when sliding the left to the right? Do you have some suggestions or examples that could help me achieve this effect?

```js
    $(function() {
  $(".drag-me").draggable({
    containment: $(".drag-area"),
    drag: function(e, ui) {

    }
  });
});
```

```css
.drag-area {
    width: 400px;
    height: 30px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    position: relative;
    margin: 100px 80px;
  }
  
  .drag-me {
    width: 70px;
    height: 30px;
    background: blue;
    position: absolute;
    top: 1px;
    left: 40px;
    opacity: 0.6;
  }
  
  .point {
    position: absolute;
  }
  
  .path {
    position: absolute;
    background: red;
    z-index: -1;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 400px;
    height: 30px;
  }
  
  .finish {
    top: 0px;
    left: 300px;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="drag-area">
  <div class="start point">
    <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/2KXTO.png" width="100px" />
  </div>

  <div class="path"></div>

  <div class="finish point">
    <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/FwmW1.png" width="100px" />
  </div>
  <div class="drag-me">
    <p style="color:white; margin: 5px; opacity:0.4px;">move me</p><img src="http://covcathdesign.org/sitebuilder/images/mounir-pixel-315x360.png" width="80px" style=" opacity:1;"></div>
</div>
```